# PHP: remove from string_array_A all strings contained in string_array_B

Tags: php, arrays, string

what I need is quite simple (for real php programmers :-D )
I have 2 strings array.
string_array_A contains a set of words contained in a post on my forum
string_array_B contains a set of words I don't want to be indexed in the search engine of my forum (just for db occupation reason).
So I would like to remove, from string_array_A, all the words contained in the string_array_B.
I would do 2 while loop, but maybe there are some high level functions I could use.
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

[`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff) is probably what you're looking for:

```
$result = array_diff($string_array_A, $string_array_B);
```

This will return an array containing values from `$string_array_A` that are not present in `$string_array_B`.

Example:

```
$string_array_A = ['foo','bar','baz'];
$string_array_B = ['baz','bak','qux'];

$result = array_diff($string_array_A, $string_array_B);

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/116168)